# SSH Tunnelling: How can I stop users being able to access services bound to localhost via port forwarding?

Tags: security, ssh

I want to be able to offer ssh accounts on my linux server for people to be able to use for SSH tunnelling. All accounts will be locked down with no interactive shell, for tunnelling / port forwarding purposes only. My problem is that I don't want them to be able to access services that are bound to localhost only by doing port forwards like the following:

```
ssh account@server -L 9999:127.0.0.1:3306 & telnet localhost 9999
```

Would give access to the default mysql database port.. How can I stop this?

I see options in the configuration file for OpenSSH to allow specific ports/hosts, but not to block them. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Using permitopen="host:port" blocks any host/port that is not mentioned. But what's your rationale for wanting to block this feature?

Comment: I want users to be able to use this as a general proxy service, on whatever port they choose to whatever they choose. The only limitations would be that they cannot connect to the local server resources besides ssh as it's a security risk with no legitimate need for the users to access things like my db server directly.

Having to specifically allow big ranges of ports is a last resort, I'd much prefer to block about 10 ports, or any forwarding to localhost specifically

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want permitopen, documented in sshd(8):

```
 permitopen="host:port"
         Limit local ``ssh -L'' port forwarding such that it may only
         connect to the specified host and port.  IPv6 addresses can be
         specified by enclosing the address in square brackets.  Multiple
         permitopen options may be applied separated by commas.  No
         pattern matching is performed on the specified hostnames, they
         must be literal domains or addresses.
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my original question I am aware of this - what I'm looking for is the opposite. Basically wanting to allow connections to any host, except for localhost..

Comment: OpenSSH does not do this. You need help from your OS. If you're running OpenBSD, pf can block or pass users (or groups) in firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use iptables, something like this should work out:
**iptables -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j DROP**  You should make a script as well if you want to have your firewall configuration persistent against reboots.